# Get total count and comments with posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the total likes and total count of the every post in a single query with the help of joins.

I am using this query. but the result is wrong

```sql
SELECT blog.id, count(blog_comments.id) as likes , count(blog_likes.id) as comments
FROM blog LEFT JOIN
     blog_comments
     ON blog.id = blog_comments.blog_id LEFT JOIN
     blog_likes
     ON blog.id = blog_likes.blog_id 
GROUP BY blog.id
```

Please check the image for table structure:
[image]

Comment: What is the result of that query and what should it be? Is the issue PHP specific?

Comment: it show total like 8 but there is only 2 records in the blog_likes table with blog_id = 2

Comment: You shouldn't have same values in column id in blog_likes

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are aggregating along two dimensions at the same time.  The produces a Cartesian product -- a row with each like pairs with each comment, for a total of `l * c` rows.

The simplest way to fix this is to use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT b.id, count(DISTINCT bl.id) as likes , count(DISTINCT bc.id) as comments
FROM blog b LEFT JOIN
     blog_comments bc
     ON b.id = bc.blog_id LEFT JOIN
     blog_likes
     ON b.id = bl.blog_id 
GROUP BY b.id;
```

If you have posts that have lots of likes and lots of comments, this is not recommended, because it creates a Cartesian product of the two.

There are several solutions for this, but I would recommend correlated subqueries:

```
select b.id,
       (select count(*) from blog_likes bl where bl.blog_id = b.id) as likes,
       (select count(*) from blog_comments bc where bc.blog_id = b.id) as comments
from blogs b;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on `blog_likes(blog_id)` and `blog_comments(blog_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is according to my table it will help you...

SELECT people.pe_name, COUNT(distinct orders.ord_id) AS num_orders, COUNT(items.item_id) AS num_items FROM people INNER JOIN orders ON orders.pe_id = people.pe_id INNER JOIN items ON items.ord_id = orders.ord_id GROUP BY people.pe_id;